# Robust estimation of probability distribution

Tags: probability, numerical-methods

I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Define the minimum of the two random variables as a new random variable $Z=\mathrm{min}\{X, Y\}$. In the experiments, I can observe the values of $X$ and $Z$. The values of these two rv all fall into the range $[l, h]$ where $0< l < h$. $Y$ can take arbitrary values greater or equal to $l$. The task is to obtain the pdf of $Y$, at least within the range of $[l,h]$.

Right now I am using the formula
$P(Z\geq z) = P(X\geq z, Y\geq z) = P(X\geq z)P(Y\geq z)$,
$1-F_Z(z) = [1-F_X(z)][1-F_Y(z)]$,
$F_Y(z) = 1- (1-F_Z(z))/(1-F_X(z))$,
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function. However, I find out that the estimated values are very unstable when getting close to the upper bound $h$. For example, negative values of $Y$'s pdf are obtained. May I ask whether there exist any robust numerical algorithms to estimate the pdf of $Y$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Define $G_X,G_Y,G_Z$ to be complementary CDFs, and $D_X,D_Y,D_Z$ to be empirical complementary CDFs from some simulation, and $d_X,d_Y,d_Z$ some kind of empirical PDFs from the same simulation. Note $G_Z=G_X G_Y$ and so $G_Y=\frac{G_Z}{G_X}$ and so $f_Y=-\frac{G_Z' G_X - G_X' G_Z}{(G_X)^2}$.

Comment: (Cont.) If I assume $d_Y$ obeys an analogous formula (and take for granted that this differentiation makes sense even for the empirical CDF which is not even continuous) then negative values are observed where $d_X D_Z < d_Z D_X$. If say $X$ and $Y$ are in fact bounded and identically distributed, this seems almost inevitable in simulation near the upper bound of their distribution, because most likely $D_Z$ is going to start to be $0$ at a somewhat lower value than $D_X$. This is all heuristics of course, but it seems like this instability is intrinsic to the problem.

Comment: Thinking about it a little more, I think a better way to pose the question is to try to calculate the *subset* of $[0,h]$ such that you have a good estimate of the PDF of $Y$ limited to that subset. Trying to get a good estimate uniformly seems hopeless because of what I mentioned in my previous comments.